# GTK fails to receive keyboard input from barcode scanner device

Tags: python, keyboard, gtk

I have a cheap Amazon-origin barcode scanner which appears as a USB keyboard. When various QR codes are scanned on Windows applications, it has no problem at all with outputting the appropriate text.

However, this text is not interpreted by any Windows GTK application I have used. This includes a custom Python application, as well as GIMP, Glade and gedit.   The exception is the space and new line characters, which are interpreted accurately.  EDIT: The problem I have is that I need this to work with my Python GTK application.

Dumping key events in Python, the keycodes returned are in the 65,000+ code point range. A short print out for some of the string "ABCDEFGH"...:

```
keyval PRS ffb0 (65456)
keyval REL ffb0 (65456)
keyval PRS ffb9 (65465)
keyval REL ffb9 (65465)
keyval PRS ffb7 (65463)
keyval REL ffb7 (65463)
keyval REL ffe9 (65513)
keyval PRS ffe9 (65513)
keyval PRS ffb0 (65456)
keyval REL ffb0 (65456)
keyval PRS ffb9 (65465)
keyval REL ffb9 (65465)
keyval PRS ffb8 (65464)
keyval REL ffb8 (65464)
keyval REL ffe9 (65513)
keyval PRS ffe9 (65513)
keyval PRS ffb0 (65456)
keyval REL ffb0 (65456)
keyval PRS ffb9 (65465)
keyval REL ffb9 (65465)
keyval PRS ffb9 (65465)
keyval REL ffb9 (65465)
keyval REL ffe9 (65513)
keyval PRS ffe9 (65513)
keyval PRS ffb1 (65457)
keyval REL ffb1 (65457)
keyval PRS ffb0 (65456)
keyval REL ffb0 (65456)
keyval PRS ffb0 (65456)
keyval REL ffb0 (65456)
keyval REL ffe9 (65513)
keyval PRS ffe9 (65513)
```

The applications have no issues accepting normal keys on a normal USB keyboard, and copy/paste works fine as well.

Most oddly, these strange key codes do not appear in other diagnostic applications, e.g. I tried to read the keycodes with Google Chrome and a bit of JS, and the more typical range of ASCII keycodes (around 65-90) were returned. And, I borrowed a much more expensive Motorola Symbol scanner, which also worked correctly. This cheap Eyoyo EY-001 scanner seems to be the only device that behaves in this way.

I have not yet tried this on Linux. That will be my next step.

It seems that this scanner is sending a weird set of extended key codes, or key codes in some unusual fashion, that GTK does not work well with.  Since codes seem to repeat, it would not appear possible to remove this encoding easily, if it is encoding at all.  Has anyone else encountered this issue?  Are there any known workarounds for this?

Comment: Normally, Stack Overflow is for issues you have during programming, or software you use for programming. Your issue is about using existing software with existing hardware, and that saddly fails outside the scope of Stackoverflow. However, since you spend a lot of effort writing your question, and even included the raw keydumps, I flagged your question for migration to SuperUser, where they with general software and hardware question, and where your question is on topic.

Comment: @ferrybig I don't believe this is a SuperUser question because it pertains to *why* a library is returning the wrong values, and how to work around that in Python.

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured it out, and it is a really bizarre cause.

The "keyboard" device is not sending actual characters. Instead, it holds `ALT`, then sends `097` and finally releases `ALT` to send `a`, for instance.  This behaviour can be captured by Pygame. It appears that GTK fails to correctly capture this operation, returning garbage data instead.

Since the `<ALT>-nnn` format is a Windows-specific way of entering keycodes, I suspect this is a slightly backwards-compatible way for the QR code scanner to send extended character sets via a keyboard interface.  However, it doesn't explain why some other keyboard emulating barcode scanners do not work in this way!

To work around this, it is necessary to pick up the ALT-keypress and decode the following three digits as an ASCII character.